# How to make openvpn to accessible to specific user only in shred ubuntu system

Tags: openvpn

I am using openvpn client to access remote server on a shared ubuntu system but while I am connected to vpn using openvpn client, other users of the shared ubuntu system are also able to access that remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make same firewall rule based on output rule and you ip address. This mining that you must have always the same ip address gived from vpn server and access the same remote ip address.

```
ufw allow out INTERFACE tcp from ADDRESS to ADDRESS
```

Also you can make rule to allow only your ip address can access to vpn

Comment: I can't configure only my ip to access vpn as other users are also need to run vpn but with different configuration. So I just want that the openvpn connection started by one user only accessible to that particular user, no other user can access that connection.

Comment: topology: `openvpn_client1 -> openvpn_server -> remote_server1`. All can connect but only `openvpn_client1` can access to `remote_server1`. Idea is to make firewall rule based on -uid or -gui. Somethig like this `iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner XXX -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx --dport x -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED  -j ACCEPT` Or like I wrote based on the source ip address. I tell you about output from vpn server to the rest of the world ...